# Duplicating sprites given the base type in javafx

Tags: javafx, cloning

I am making a game in javaFX right now. Essentially, a player knows what type of bullet it has (say SingleShot). All bullet types extend off a general Projectile class. In the player class, I have a method which needs to spawn a bullet if a button is pressed. How can I spawn a clone of the bullet given only the type it is? So if my type is SingleShot (stored as a Projectile field), how do I spawn a new SingleShot without having a bunch of if-else statements checking through every type?

```
public class Projectile extends Sprite{
int damage;
int fireRate;

public Projectile(Pane outerPane, double x, double y, double dy, double dx){
    super(outerPane,x,y,dy,dx);
    damage = 1;
    fireRate = 10;
}

public int getFireRate(){
    return this.fireRate;
}
public void setFireRate(int fr){
    fireRate=fr;
}
public int getDamage(){
    return damage;
}
public void setDamage(int d){
    damage=d;
}
}
```

This is an example bullet, but there are many others. There may also be multiple shapes/rectangles in a given bullet class.

```
public class SingleShot extends Projectile{
Rectangle bullet;
public SingleShot(Pane outerPane, double x, double y,double dy, double dx){
    super(outerPane,x,y, dy, dx);
    bullet = new Rectangle(0,0,10,10);
    bullet.setFill(Color.BLUE);
    getChildren().add(bullet);
}
}
```

Here is the player class. I have removed most of the extraneous code but if you need it please ask.

```
public class Player extends Sprite{

Rectangle plyr;
AnimationTimer timer;
boolean movingN,movingE,movingW,movingS;
boolean shootingN,shootingE,shootingW,shootingS;

Projectile bulletType;
ArrayList<Projectile> bullets;



public Player(Pane outerPane, double x, double y, double w, double h, double xv, double yv){
    bulletType = new SingleShot(this,0,0,1,1);
    bullets= new ArrayList<Projectile>();

}

private void shoot(){
        if(shootingN){
            System.out.println("North shot");
            //how to determine what shot to create? possibly have hard checker for type
            //maybe have a method which makes a copy for the projectile type, then feeds it to here and this only changes vx,vy,x,y, etc.
            Projectile shot = new SingleShot(this,plyr.getX()+0.5*plyr.getWidth(),plyr.getY(),0,-10);
            getChildren().add(shot);
            bullets.add(shot);
        }

}
```

Comment: Consider using the [Abstract Factory Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_factory_pattern).

Comment: Or simply adding a `Projectile copy(Pane outerPane, double x, double y,double dy, double dx)` method to `Projectile` or a supertype...